# VSCode and GCC and Clang trivially copyable in C++20

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++20, intellisense

VSCode intellisence appears to violate C++20 standard.

Note: I'm not good at writing in English, so I use translation.

Hello, nice to meet you.

I ran into a problem while writing the following test to verify triviality in C++20.
Let's take a quick look at the following definitions, for example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept copy_constructible = std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> ;

template<typename T>
concept trivially_copy_constructible = std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>
    && copy_constructible<T> ;


template<typename T>
struct OptionalTest
{
private:
    
    union { T _value ; alignas(T) std::byte _align[sizeof(T)] ; } ;
    bool _valid ;

public:
    
    // #1
    constexpr OptionalTest(const OptionalTest<T> &)
    requires trivially_copy_constructible<T>
    = default ;
    
    // #2
    constexpr OptionalTest(const OptionalTest<T> &other)
    requires copy_constructible<T>
    : _align { /* default */ }
    , _valid(other._valid)
    {
        if (_valid) {
            new (&_value) T { other._value } ;
        }
    }

} ;

// all true.
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<OptionalTest<int>>) ;
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<OptionalTest<int>>) ;
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<OptionalTest<int>>) ;
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_assignable_v<OptionalTest<int>>) ;
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<OptionalTest<int>>) ;

// this is false.
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<OptionalTest<int>>) ;
```

As you can see in the comments in the code above, VSCode says `OptionalTest<int>` is not trivial copyable.
But to me `OptionalTest<int>` looks trivially copyable.

Removing the definition of `#2` fixes the problem, but this appears to violate the trivial copyable constraint in C++20.

In fact, even with the definition of `#2`, `OptionalTest<int>` continues to be trivial copy-constructible as seen in the comments.

Additionally, although this issue appears in VSCode, the gcc compiler I'm using (-std=c++20 option) works as expected, making `OptionalTest<int>` trivially copyable.
clang treats it as false, just like VSCode.

Why? Is this my mistake?
If it's my compiler, should I change the code for VSCode or clang?
I want to check whether `OptionalTest<int>` in this definition is trivially copyable by the C++20 standard.

thank you.

Sidenote: The thing I most want to check is whether types like `OptionalTest<int>` are trivially copyable. Other information can be inferred incidentally by its truth.

Comment: #2 is not trivial since it is user-provided. Also, VSCode is an IDE. What IntelliSense "says" depends on which tool you're using for checking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The tool used for checking is C/C++ intellisense provided by Microsoft, and it displays errors in all architecture modes. I also believe that in C++20, a requirement for trivial copyable is that the most constrained members of the qualifying special member functions be trivial.

Or is there something wrong with my understanding of C++20?

Comment: Don't trust Intellisense. Trust only the real compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
By the way, is it safe to assume that `OptionalTest<int>` is trivially copyable?

Comment: If you find a case where intellisense disagrees with the compiler raise a bug with Microsoft then ignore intellisense and trust the compiler

Comment: ok i will,
thanks for your attention.
However, I'm still not clear on which bug it is, so I'd like to clarify that.
At least in clang it matches so.